# Use the method parameters of expect in the andReturn

Tags: java, junit, easymock

```
Collection<T_SI_IDABAREME> tSiIdabaremes;
DAO_F_IDA_DESC mockDaoFIdaDesc

prepareExpects(){
     expect(mockDaoTSiIdabareme.findByDate(isA(Date.class)))
          .andReturn(searchByParameter(tSiIdabaremes, date));
}
```

Is it possible to use the **date** that will be passed to the findByDate in the andReturn?

PS: This is a service test class and I'm doing it in a way to bypass the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
expect(mockDaoTSiIdabareme.findByDate(isA(Date.class)))
     .andReturn(searchByParameter(tSiIdabaremes, date));
```

I should have put

```
expect(mockDaoTSiIdabareme.findByDate(isA(Date.class)))
         .andAnswer(new IAnswer<Collection<T_SI_IDABAREME>>() {
              public Collection<T_SI_IDABAREME> answer() throws Throwable {
                  return searchByParameter((Date)getCurrentArguments()[0]);
              } 
         }
);
```

Which will only look for the return value when the method is being exectued and then we can use getCurrentArguments() to retrieve the arguments passed to the method.

You can find more about this in the [EasyMock Documentation](http://easymock.org/user-guide.html#verification-creating).

Answer (score 1):

whenever you use expect method like this

```
Easymock.expect(someMethod(Date.Class)).andReturn(something);
```

you are instructing compiler to mock all calls to that method whenever **ANY** object of Date class is passed as parameter,and you will not be able to use that object in return expression.

on the other hand if you have something like this,

```
Easymock.expect(someMethod(someSpecificDateObject)).andReturn(someSpecificDateObject);
```

you are instructing the compiler to mock this method call **ONLY** when a specific object of Date class is passed as parameter(`someSpecificDateObject` in this case) and you will be able to use this parameter while returning, because you know that method gets mocked only when this object is passed.

You can use second option if it is favourable to you,but with first option what you ask is not possible.

Hope this helps!

Good luck!